# Compressor grounding out on a 5 year old unit

Tags: compressor

Our 5ton AC unit stopped cooling. Fan runs but it’s not cooling. Have had the circuit breaker replaced when AC company indicated that was the problem. Now the compressor is grounding out and the AC company recommends replacing compressor or the entire outside unit.

Comment: Might be time to find another AC company.  A circuit breaker is on or off.  If AC has power(fan is running), the breaker is working.   Changing the breaker will not cause the compressor to ground out.  If the compressor is grounding out, then the breaker should trip.  If it does not, get an licensed electrician in to check what that AC company did(and send them the bill).

Comment: Electrician installed a new breaker but I it kept flipping the switch. The AC company came out again today and now saying the unit still causes circuit breaker to flip so it’s grounding out. Then recommends new entire unit outside or new compressor. Edited to add: this is in Texas with 100 plus right now

Comment: Edit new information into your question.  What did the AC unit do before, just run the fan without cool air?  It sounds like you might have been low on refrigerant or a leak, maybe the compressor frosted over.

Comment: what is `grounding out` is the compressor running or not

Comment: Oh Man, what $ h i ty  diagnosis. Just started throwing parts at it an hope it gets fixed.  TERRIBLE.     First thing to check by a competent tech would be to use an amp clamp meter and see if there was indeed current flowing to ground.  If so trace it back to the source.   Your tech is incompetent.

Comment: The tech reportedly checked the amp and the unit is getting power outside but not cooling inside. In other words it’s about 82 degrees inside and it’s just blowing hot air right now. We do have two units a 3 ton (I think) and a 5 ton. The smaller second unit is working.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of events might have played as following.

Your system developed a coolant leak somewhere.

Then it dried out (no coolant at all)

Eventually the compressor overheated and shorted out triggering the circuit breaker. New breaker will not fix anything. Ask for your money back.

Ask the AC expert to check /find and repair the leak.

Now you can contemplate if just replace the compressor or get completely new outdoor unit. Price difference is significant.